# jQuery 1.9.1 Several Checkboxes Selection

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-1.9

I have this code [1] for check/uncheck several checkbox elements in a page. It works good on jQuery versions previous to 1.9.1 but for some reason it doesn't on 1.9.1 or newer

Basically, what I do is:

```
$('.cbx').attr('checked', false);
```

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/qNPCH/4/

Do you know how can I achieve this with newer versions of jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('.cbx').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Has backwards compatibility to at least jQuery 1.6